# What is the safest way to log off or shutdown a dual booted Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, dual-boot

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS dual booted with primary Windows 10 Home
operating system. My laptop (Acer Predator) has a NVIDIA graphic card. It has happened
to me recently when I left my laptop for a while (current OS = ubuntu) and forgot to connect
the charger. Due to screen timeout, it went to sleep and then I tried
to wake it up, but soon after that due to low battery (became zero), it
shut down.

Then when I tried to switch on my laptop, the Grub menu was
loading fine but Ubuntu froze at the boot up. It ran some weird
scripts relating to sda/clean and inodes and then the screen froze. I
tried to shut it down and again run, but the screen froze and I wasn't able to log in again. As a result I had to reinstall Ubuntu. Obviously I tried repairing Grub etc too before doing that.

Then I searched that ubuntu does not work well with NVIDIA and in addition to that, it might get corrupted due to power failure or shut downs and sleeps.

Of course, I have to some day or the other, put my laptop to sleep after working on Ubuntu and sometimes shut it down.

Will it corrupt my boot loader or any other files if I put my laptop
to sleep or shut it down?

Can you suggest me some good practices?

This was the screen freezing state.
What approaches I did to resolve it?

1. I shut down the pc and restarted it. Grub menu was opening. I opened Ubuntu using that but the same screen showed.
2. I opened the grub command line and applied various commands by referring to https://itsfoss.com/fix-ubuntu-freezing/ . Still did not went well.
3. I went to windows and repaired(using windows default repair disk) my D drive where ubuntu had the partition. Later, i realized that repairing might delete files too. That was another mistake on my part.
4. Then i tried to repair my grub using bootable pendrive and boot-repair.
5. Final Resort: Reinstall ubuntu.

Note:[image]
I had problems with boot loader, which is my strongest guess.

**I just want to know what are the practices I should follow while powering off or logging off from ubuntu, so that the above problem or any other unpredictable power issues do not happen.**

Comment: You say that the screen freezes. What is on your screen when it freezes? Are you able to get a command line prompt by typing ALT-Fx (where Fx is function key number "x") or CTL-ALT-Fx? Note that the messages about sda are expected, since your PC was unable to save in-memory copies of disk blocks before switching off, and left your filesystem in an inconsistent state. In most cases, those inconsistencies are repaired automatically.

Comment: Hi @berndbausch, I have made changes in my problem statement, so that you could analyze it better. Thanks!

Comment: One thing you should **not** do is attempting to repair a Linux disk with Windows tools. You should also **avoid cutting power without a proper shutdown**, which is precisely what happened when you put the computer in sleep mode, then let the battery run empty. As I remarked, this usually doesn't cause problems with the disk, but there is no guarantee it doesn't. Next time it freezes, remove the `quiet` option from Grub. Without `quiet`, the kernel will display startup messages, which are very useful for troubleshooting. Also use the key combinations I mentioned to get a command line prompt.

Comment: Thanks @berndbausch, I will keep these things in mind!